# Why `bm` uparrow gives extra white space while `bm` downarrow does not?

Tags: math-mode, bm

As topic. I am using pdfLaTeX compiler on Overleaf.

I've figured out a remedy (?) as topic by not bolding the arrow: `\bm{a_{xxx}}{}_{\uparrow}`. However, I want to know the reason that `\bm{a_{xxx\uparrow}}` gives an extra white space after the `\uparrow` symbol that `\bm{a_{xxx\downarrow}}` would not do so.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym,amssymb,enumerate,amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace,color,graphicx,mathtools,yhmath}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption,cancel}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \bm{a_{xxx\uparrow}}(i), \bm{a_{xxx\downarrow}}(i).
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result using the built-in PDF compiler is [image: uparrow vs downarrow]

Comment: It would help a lot if you wouldn't show only some snippets but a full example.

Comment: why do you add hyperref, natbib, ulem, subcaption etc to your example? Are they relevant? Side remark: epsfig is outdated since more than 20 years.

Comment: I see. I need them (except epsfig which I found no error) in my original script but I can remove it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suspect that remark it's about this site not rendering. But the issue is in fact really interesting: `\bm{\uparrow}` adds a space on the right in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, and no bracing seems to have an effect.

Comment: @campa yes looking at the code now, something odd happening, I need to find somewhere to blame that isn't bm of course.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bug in `cmbsy7.tfm`: the characters used are octal 42 (up arrow) and octal 43 (down arrow) and we see in the tfm file (converted to human readable form)

```
(FAMILY CMBSY V2.2)
(FACE O 360)
(CODINGSCHEME TEX MATH SYMBOLS)
(DESIGNSIZE R 7.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
[...]
(CHARACTER O 42
   (CHARWD R 0.65516)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (CHARDP R 0.194445)
   (CHARIC R 0.714683)
   )
(CHARACTER O 43
   (CHARWD R 0.65516)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (CHARDP R 0.194445)
   )
[...]
```

and the italic correction makes all the difference, because by rule TeX adds the italic correction when a symbol ends a math list. The italic correction ends up as 0.714683 times 7 points, a whopping 5pt!

Indeed, if I try `$x_{\bm{\uparrow}}x_{\bm{\downarrow}}$` I get

```
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\hbox(4.8611+1.3611)x10.08888, shifted 1.49998
.....\hbox(4.8611+1.3611)x9.58888
......\mathon
......\OMS/cmsy/b/n/7 "
......\kern5.00278
......\mathoff
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\hbox(4.8611+1.3611)x5.0861, shifted 1.49998
.....\hbox(4.8611+1.3611)x4.5861
......\mathon
......\OMS/cmsy/b/n/7 #
......\mathoff
```

and you see the added kern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand\fixup{\kern-\fontcharic\scriptfont2`\"}

\begin{document}

$x_{\bm{\uparrow\fixup}x_{\bm{\downarrow}}x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another fix could be

```
\newcommand{\fixup}{_{\kern-\scriptspace}}
```

The first suggested hack doesn't work with superscripts to the arrow, the second one would; however in case you have a subscript to the arrow, it will remove the wrong italic correction by itself.

The problem starts with the METAFONT source code by Knuth himself. We see in `sym.mf`

```
iff known down_arrow: cmchar "Downward arrow";
beginchar(down_arrow,9u#,asc_height#,asc_depth#);
adjust_fit(0,0); pickup crisp.nib;
pos1(rule_thickness,0); pos2(rule_thickness,0);
pos3(rule_thickness,90); pos4(rule_thickness,90);
lft x1l=hround(.5w-.5rule_thickness); y1+.5rule_thickness=h;
x0=x1=x2; bot y0=-d; x0-x3=x4-x0=if monospace:3u else:4u fi+eps;
y3=y4=y0+if monospace:.24 else:.36 fi asc_height+eps;
pos5(rule_thickness,angle(z4-z0)); z5l=z0;
pos6(rule_thickness,angle(z3-z0)); z6l=z0;
z9=.2[.5[z3,z4],z0];
numeric t; path p; p=z4r{z9-z4}..z6r;
t=xpart(p intersectiontimes((x2r,-d)--(x2r,h))); y2=ypart point t of p;
filldraw z0..{z4-z9}z4l--subpath (0,t) of\\(z4r{z9-z4}..z6r)
 ---z1r..z1l---subpath (t,0) of\\(z3r{z9-z3}..z5r)
 --z3l{z9-z3}..z0 & cycle;  % arrowhead and stem
penlabels(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,9); endchar;

iff known up_arrow: cmchar "Upward arrow";
beginchar(up_arrow,9u#,asc_height#,asc_depth#);
italcorr .76asc_height#*slant+.5crisp#-u#;
adjust_fit(0,0); pickup crisp.nib;
pos1(rule_thickness,0); pos2(rule_thickness,0);
pos3(rule_thickness,90); pos4(rule_thickness,90);
lft x1l=hround(.5w-.5rule_thickness); y1-.5rule_thickness=-d;
x0=x1=x2; top y0=h; x0-x3=x4-x0=if monospace:3u else:4u fi+eps;
y3=y4=y0-if monospace:.24 else:.36 fi asc_height-eps;
pos5(rule_thickness,angle(z4-z0)); z5l=z0;
pos6(rule_thickness,angle(z3-z0)); z6l=z0;
z9=.2[.5[z3,z4],z0];
numeric t; path p; p=z4l{z9-z4}..z6r;
t=xpart(p intersectiontimes((x2r,-d)--(x2r,h))); y2=ypart point t of p;
filldraw z0..{z4-z9}z4r--subpath (0,t) of\\(z4l{z9-z4}..z6r)
 ---z1r..z1l---subpath (t,0) of\\(z3l{z9-z3}..z5r)
 --z3r{z9-z3}..z0 & cycle;  % arrowhead and stem
penlabels(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,9); endchar;
```

and there should be a reason for the italic correction in “up arrow” that isn't in “down arrow”. Anyway, this italic correction turns out to be negative, and so it is discarded, in `cmsy5` to `cmsy10`.

The real bug is in `cmbsy7.mf` (in `cmextra`, provided by the AMS) which has

```
crisp#:=11pt#;    % diameter of serif corners
```

Similarly, `cmbsy5.mf` has 9pt, whereas `cmsy7.mf` has

```
crisp#:=7/36pt#;    % diameter of serif corners
```

That's the issue. Indeed, `cmbsy10.mf` has

```
crisp#:=13/36pt#;    % diameter of serif corners
```

Similar bugs affect `cmbsy5.mf`, `cmbsy6.mf` and `cmbsy8.mf`, but not `cmbsy9.mf` and `cmbsy10.mf`.

Comment: not just 7 all the smaller fonts, and not just cm, latin modern has copied this :(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\downarrow` has no italic correction, as you see.

Comment: I think it is cmbsy8 in the example. That has an even bigger italic correction!

Comment: Useful remedy. Accepted.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Yes, indeed. I removed the 12pt option. However, from my investigation, `cmbsy9` is immune from the bug, but all lower sizes have it.

Comment: Did @egreg blame Knuth for this!

Comment: @DDuck Oh, not at all! The bug is in the files made by the AMS.

Comment: It makes sense to have an italic correction on the up arrow and not the down arrow. Think of the bold roman "f" which has an italic correction.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Yes, but this italic correction seems to be specially crafted for having no effect (unless `crisp` is set to a very large value).

Comment: Which is a good reason to "blame Knuth for this".

Answer (score 9):

[image]

This appears to be a bug in the bold cm font at script size, the example can be reduced to

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

$\scriptstyle x\uparrow y \downarrow z$

\boldmath
$\scriptstyle x\uparrow y\downarrow z$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Congratulations on having managed to blame someone else `:-D`

Comment: So it's a bug bruh. Whom can we report this bug to?

Comment: @campa that is of course the most important thing. This is a "feature" in the AMS cmextra bold math fonts, somewhat oddly copied to latin modern math, adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` doesn't help.

Comment: @Yuki.F I am just wondering. The fonts are from the AMS originally, but the latin modern fonts have copied this. I am _assuming_ it's a bug as I can think of no good reason for it, but strange it's in latin modern as well.